# use load_dynamic from string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-importlib

I'm trying to load a module from a string, but it's also an `.so` file. This works:

```
import  imp
mod = imp.load_dynamic('module.name','path/to/my_module.so')
mod.function(x)
```

But I want to load the module from a Python string. I tried creating a custom class with a read method and passing that in:

```
s = string_with_read('.so file text....')
mod = imp.load_dynamic('module.name',s)
```

But it tells me `TypeError: must be string, not instance`. So, it wants a path to a file. Is there anyway I can make a fake file and pass it in instead? I'm open to using python3 or the newer import module, `importlib`; `imp` just seemed easier.

Here is the `string_with_read` class, though that approach isn't working currently.

```
class string_with_read:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s
    def read(self):
        return self.s
    def readlines(self):
        return self.s.splitlines()
```

Comment: so `string_with_read` is a string?

Comment: I tried creating a barebones class from a string with `read` and `readline` methods. I can post it's definiition.

Comment: I thought maybe it would take a file instance instead of a path, and that it would not check the type but just read :) I'm considering modifying the source code but I can't really find it...

Comment: Do you mean something like http://pastebin.com/gNju2G4f?

Comment: It looks like it may work, let me fiddle with it. I'm starting with the text of a `.so` file, which is apparently already compiled. Thank you :)

Comment: No worries, this might be useful too http://pastebin.com/MewJDRty